# Force a component library to use host dependencies

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm developing a react component library that is using axios:

1. I put axios in the `devDependencies` in order to develope, and in the `peerDependencies`.
2. In `rollup.config.ts`, I put axios inside "external" props, so it won't get builded with my code.

   export default [
   {

   ```
   input: "src/index.ts",
   output: [
     {
       file: packageJson.main,
       format: "cjs",
       sourcemap: true,
     },
     {
       file: packageJson.module,
       format: "esm",
       sourcemap: true,
     },
   ],
   plugins: [
     resolve(),
     commonjs(),
     typescript({ tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json" }),
     json(),
   ],
   external: ['react-dom', 'axios', 'react-redux', 'react', '@reduxjs/toolkit', 'react-audio-player']
   ```

   },
   {

   ```
   input: "dist/esm/index.d.ts",
   output: [{ file: "dist/index.d.ts", format: "esm" }],
   plugins: [dts()]
   ```

   },
   ];
3. Then from my component library I npm-linked react and axios:

> npm link  ../path-to-host/node_modules/react
>
> npm link  ../path-to-host/node_modules/axios

4. Then from my component library root I created an sym-link with `npm link`
5. From my host project I recall the sym link with `npm link <libray-name>`

In my host project I do some setup to axios (interceptors and headers) that are not catched by my component library, which sends "raw" request. This makes me wander that the component library is still using its own axios instead of the one from the host project.

How can I force my component library to consume the same dependencies of the host project?

**UPDATE**

Somehow it starts to works correctly sometimes, and sometimes not: I symlinked axios and react but its like the link doesn't affect the project consistently, rather they works at blinks.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is the correct way to achieve what you are after, but it has given me the best results with my rough investigating in the past.

**Problem As I Understand It**

Dependencies are first attempted to be resolved from the local node_module folder before checking the root node module folder.

*For Example:*

With the directory structure:

```
    Host Project Root
    |- src
    |- node_modules
    |  |- react
    |  |- component-library
    |  |  |- node_modules
    |  |  |  |- react
```

When bundling the `component-library` package any import for `react` will resolve to: `./node_modules/component-libaray/node_modules/react`
Which is not the same as any import for `react` from the Host Projects `./src` which would resolve to: `./node_modules/react`

*Why is this a problem?*

This causes any constant values / objects from the duplicated import (`react` in the above example) to be different for the imported package (`component-libaray`) and the host code (`.src`).

For React this means that things such as Contexts used by both host code (`./src`) and imported package (`component-library`) will not be able to see each others data as there state will be held in separate React constants that have no connection to each other in the generated bundle.

**Any Solutions?!**

*What about `npm dedupe`?*

Well if your goal is to run a watch on both host code (`./src`) and imported package (`component-library`) for concurrent development purposes then `npm dedupe` will most likely mangle the node modules for the imported package (`component-library`) and cause its build to fail, this is far from ideal.

*A Solution (kind of)*

To make it so that it is possible to be able to run a watch on both host code (`./src`) and the imported package (`component-library`) and not cause an issue with unwanted duplicate packages in the resulting bundle it's possible to use aliases with some limitations.

Webpack Example:

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');

const config = {
    /* Other webpack config  */
    resolve: {
        alias: {

        }
    }
}

// load in package.json
let packageJson = fs.readFileSync('./package.json');
let package = JSON.parse(packageJson);

// loop through all dependencies in package.json and add aliases
// The aliases added below will ensure that all imports for a given package will
// resolve to "./node_modules/package" instead of the possible 
// "./node_modules/component-library/node_modules/package"
if (package?.dependencies) {
    Object.keys(package.dependencies).forEach(key => {
        config.resolve.alias[key] = path.resolve(`./node_modules/${key}`);
    })
}

// This is the same as the snippet but for devDependencies
// This should not be needed (which is why it is commented out)
// devDependencies are intended to not make it into the resulting bundle
// and should therefore not cause any issues.
// It can be uncommented if you want a scorched earth approach.
/*
 * if (package?.devDependencies) {
 *     Object.keys(package.devDependencies).forEach(key => {
 *         config.resolve.alias[key] = path.resolve(`./node_modules/${key}`);
 *     })
 * }
 */
```

ViteJs Example:

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const path = require('path');

// helper to resolve path names.
function pathResolve(dir) {
  return path.resolve(__dirname, '.', dir)
}

// load in package.json
let packageJson = fs.readFileSync('./package.json');
let package = JSON.parse(packageJson);

// array to hold aliases to be added to vite config.
const resolveNodeModules: any[] = []

// loop through all dependencies in package.json and add aliases
// The aliases added below will ensure that all imports for a given package will
// resolve to "./node_modules/package" instead of the possible 
// "./node_modules/component-library/node_modules/package"
if (packageJson?.dependencies) {
    Object.keys(packageJson.dependencies).forEach(key => {
        resolveNodeModules.push({
            find: key,
            replacement: pathResolve('node_modules') + '/' + key
        });
    })
}

// This is the same as the snippet but for devDependencies
// This should not be needed (which is why it is commented out)
// devDependencies are intended to not make it into the resulting bundle
// and should therefore not cause any issues.
// It can be uncommented if you want a scorched earth approach.
/* if (packageJson?.devDependencies) {
 *     Object.keys(packageJson.devDependencies).forEach(key => {
 *         resolveNodeModules.push({
 *             find: key,
 *             replacement: pathResolve('node_modules') + '/' + key
 *         });
 *     })
 * }
 */

const config = {
    resolve: {
        alias: [
            ...resolveNodeModules
            /* Other aliases here if required i.e. { find: /@\//, replacement: pathResolve('src') + '/' }
        ]
    }
}
```

I haven't used rollup directly only via ViteJs which provides a preconfigured rollup. I think ViteJs just uses `@rollup/plugin-alias` which should just be able to take the same `resolveNodeModules` value from the ViteJs example above.

**Limitations**

1. All dependencies that are shared by the host code (`./src`) and the imported package (`component-library`) must be in the host projects `package.json` in the `dependencies` section. This includes packages that are dependencies of dependencies.
2. All dependencies have to be happy with the version that is being force resolved, i.e. if two packages use `random-package` but one requires `v1.0.0` and the other requires `v8.0.0` usually without the forced resolution via the alias this would be bundled as two separate versions of the package, but with the aliases it would be bundled as a single version which might not work for both importing packages due to breaking changes between versions.

**Conclusion**

Is this a proper solution to your problem? **No**

Does this work? **Yes/Sometimes** - success rate is good for projects that have dependencies with versions that were created from around the same time period as each other. This usually means there is a smaller chance of occurrence for limitation 2.

Hopefully someone else will come along and have an easier more robust solution and we both will have learned something, but for now I hope this at least assists in understanding the problem.

Comment: First thanks for sharing your solutions. Second, in a world full of react component libraries, how it comes that there is no official guide/tools to develop those?
Each one has to find its own way?

Comment: I think that this is an edge case, the preferred method for developing a component library would be to do it all separate from the any project that would end up using it with a preview/storyboard/example setup in the library so you can easily see the components you are making.